# ASP.NET MVC MySQL Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

I'm learning how to use MVC template to create ASP.NET web applications.
As the title states, I'm using MySql, I can see the connection in the `server explorer > Data Connections`, from where I got the `connectionString` and it's properly connected.

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

is the error I'm getting when I try to save data to the (currently empty) database.
This is my `connectionString`

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbname" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dbname" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

The error I'm getting is in the following line

```
public static int SavedData<T>(string sql, T data)
{
    using (IDbConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        return cnn.Execute(sql, data); //here is the error
    }
}
```

I don't understand. It says the error is for the user and it isn't using a password? A password is being used, and it's properly set. Any ideas on how to fix this? I've read many other threads but those mainly have errors in the password or the configuration using other tools like xampp, php, etc, which isn't my case.

EDIT:

I followed this tutorial which uses SQL and not MySql, and uses a tool called Dapper which I don't know what it is used for, in the stacktrace I see the following errors

```
Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command, Action`2 paramReader) +85
   Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) +763
   Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) +117
```

I'm currently investigating about dapper with MySQL.

Edit 2:

I tried modifying the connection string, all values are correctly set. But I still get exactly the same error, I didn't think that was the actual problem (I had to modify the root password because I was using double quotes and # in the password. Anyways, this is how it looks now, and the connection is tested and works OK.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="dbname" connectionString="Persist Security Info=False;database=dbname;server=localhost;Connect Timeout=30;user id=root; pwd=_password" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: does the user root exist in your database settings? also, what is your sql query? what's the name of the table, etc...

Comment: Yes @GlennvanAcker as I said, the user and the password are properly set, I can see the databases in Data Connections, the connection test works properly, and I can also see it for the root user in the MySQL workbench, is not a problem of user and password, that's why I don't understand the error.

Comment: I don't see a password in your connectionstring, are you using one?

Comment: Yes, of course I am. You can add connections in visual studio, and set the password there, then you can copy the connection string from the added connection which hides the password

Comment: but you're creating an assembly, and running that. therefor, there is no password when debugging or running, since you didn't change the connection string to explicitly include it.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker so, what you are saying is that Visual Studio is yelling at me that no password has been set in the connection string? I'll try adding it, my password has a " (doble quotes) character in it, perhaps it was a mistake to set that character in the password smh

Comment: @GlennvanAcker I tried modifying the connectionString adding my password, and I get the very same error

Comment: it still says that there's no password? check your password policy in sql management studio.

Comment: I'm not using MySQL, not SQL. It still says using password:NO. I don't know what it is...

Comment: it makes no difference, sql management studio is a tool to manage your databases and tables. there you can easily check your users, and credentials, and test connections and queries

Comment: Yeah... I'm not gonna install that. Is not a password problem.

Comment: Obviously it is, since that's what sql is complaining about. try checking your permissions in the console then.

Comment: "If you get an error message that contains using password: NO, it means that you tried to log in without a password." (from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html) what permissions do you want me to check?

Comment: everything for your root user, both on the database and on the table.

Comment: You need to show the implementation of `GetConnectionString` in your question. If you're having trouble with your connection string, it's a gaping problem with your question if you leave out the code that's supposed to actually get it for you.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker You're referring to SQL Server Management Studio? That's for Microsoft's SQL Server. Not MySQL.

Comment: It doesn't matter, SSMS supports mysql

Comment: @GlennvanAcker No, not really. SSMS supports ODBC via linked servers, and you can get an ODBC driver for MySQL. But that's not full support. There are plenty of tools that have full support for MySQL. If you're trying to troubleshoot a problem with MySQL, it makes far more sense to recommend them than it does SSMS. You're just making noise by saying to use SSMS here. I suggest you remove those comments to reduce the noise here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the code was pretty easy to follow, also what I wanted to do, but I understand that more experienced programmers may have considered it incomplete now. 
What I was trying to do was to save data, and was unable to, due to an **access denied** type of error, which I think comes from the way Visual Studio handles the projects that can be added as SQL server projects, which I couldn't do with a MySQL project (in the tutorial I was following, he copied the string from the server explorer project he added and then pasted it in connectionString on web.config, which clearly didn't work for me), I also learnt my lesson about the `GetConnectionString()` method, which wasn't explained in my question, that's why it was voted for closing the question, but I knew it was working (maybe was not doing what it was supposed to, though; I got rid of it), still, perhaps the problem was there.
so I ended up doing the following, which works OK

```
public static void SavedData(int _SomeField)
{

    FooModel data = new FooModel
    {
        SomeField = _SomeField
    };

    MySqlConnection dbConnection;

    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    connectionBuilder.Server = "localhost";
    connectionBuilder.UserID = "root";
    connectionBuilder.Password = "password";
    connectionBuilder.Database = "foo";

    dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionBuilder.ToString());


    String query = String.Format("insert into foo.foo (SomeField) values ('{0}')", @data.SomeField);

    dbConnection.Open();

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConnection);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dbConnection.Close();

}
```

Comment: just to take that out of the way, can you post the code for GetConnectionString method? was it a code from yours or a method from some lib? at the beginning, were you reading the connection string from the app.config or were you building it?